# PHP configuration with Apache Error: Apache won't start

Tags: php, apache, windows-server-2008

I am using Apache 2.2.25 with PHP5.4.17. I installed this on my own Windows 64bit machine and it worked fine without issues. Now I'm trying to install the same system on a new machine but when I change the Apache configuration to work with PHP, it won't start.

Here is the relevant part of httpd.conf:

```
#Line 130 below    
LoadModule php5_module "C:/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/PHP"
```

This is the error is Apache logs/error file:

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 130 of C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/php/php5apache2_2.dll into server: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.  

[Mon Nov 11 21:19:37 2013] [warn] (OS 995)The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.  : winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed.
```

I read up on the error and almost 99% of the solutions mentioned version compatibility but since this exact setup worked on another machine, I'm thinking it must be something else. Any help with how I can find the problem would be appreciated.

**Update**
Since my colleague is doing this installation and I'm giving remote support, I just found out that his machine is actually "Windows Server 2008". I tried more research about it and many solutions included installing VC++ so I did but still no response.

Thanks

Comment: A crazy thought but does `C:/php/php5apache2_2.dll` exist?

Comment: maybe this ? http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/this-application-failed-to-start-because-side-by/7673bf12-87c2-48ca-b5ae-b8aa85e295dc

Comment: Add previous line of config.

Comment: `C:/php/php5apache2_2.dll` does. Also tried it with `php5apache2_4.dll` which also exists, same error.

Comment: @Joe T Thanks for the link, I attempted the scan but no issues were found.
@sectus you mean before `LoadModule` ?

Comment: New version of PHP for windows are not compatible with apache downloaded from its home project site, you should use the builds at apachefriends.

Comment: @Matteo Tassinari As in XAMPP?

Comment: Well, I don't know where you took Apache and PHP, but yes, XAMPP should work "out of the box".

Comment: I got them from the main sites (ApacheLounge and PHP.net) and I got the installation working on Windows 7 64bit. The issue now is on Windows Server 2008 64bit. As for XAMPP, is that good for Production? Because I read that, for security reasons, it's preferable to use the "main" setups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the installation environment "changed" from when I asked the question, I did try to install using different versions but it **wasn't** compatibility of Apache with PHP which I mentioned wasn't the case here but rather the Apache/PHP installation with the System.

I used `Apache2.2.15` with `PHP5.3.2` and the system was up and running. Thanks for the comments everyone.